# iTunes checkboxes won't select without multiple attempts

Tags: itunes, troubleshooting

When adding and subtracting podcasts on iPhones that connect to a particular computer, the checkboxes require clicking again and again until you eventually get them to check, or uncheck, whichever you try to do.
So it usually takes 4-6 attempts for each item and really is an annoyance.
Have looked through every menu, but saw nothing that seemed to relate to this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like lag to me. Have you tried waiting before you click again?

Comment: it is not that it is being clicked rapidly, it is that when you click it checks and the keyup unchecks it, or it never seems to check at all. I have done this slowly, thought it was a faulty mouse, scanned for keyloggers, everything I can think of. It just behaves poorly